# Mikrotik - Route Specific IP over VPN

Tags: vpn, route, pptp, mikrotik

I have a PPTP VPN connection setup on my Mikrotik router. I would like to route only one IP on my local network over that VPN Connection. All traffic for that IP address can be routed over VPN.

How does one go about setting it up on the Mikrotik router? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible; you just have to add a new route rule to send traffic to your specific IP via the pptp peer address.

For example, if you have

- PPTP local address 10.50.0.2
- PPTP remote address 10.50.0.1
- The internet IP you want to route: 31.32.33.34

your route will be

```
/ip route
add distance=1 dst-address=31.32.33.34/32 gateway=10.50.0.1
```

Of course, your peer 10.50.0.1 must have NAT enabled also, if the destination address is a public IP.